# Gmail API: uploading attachment once for multiple emails

Tags: gmail-api

I am reading this documentation, it says:
*The Gmail API allows you to upload file data when creating or updating a draft or when inserting or sending a message.* 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads

I am trying to upload an attachment to use for multiple emails. Emails have different content, but all with same attachment. Can I use the upload methods specified above to upload the attachment just once and then use it in sending multiple emails?

Comment: Well, you can upload the attachment by using any one of the three methods, just save your attachment in your drive to store and send it for multiple emails by specifying the file IDs that are included in the outgoing messages. 

Check this [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20132-gmail-api-send-mail-attachments) on how to use the Gmail API to Send Emails with Attachments by using apps Script.

Comment: @KENdi thanks for the link. However in the tutorial it still fetches the file from the drive in the getAttachment function, and uploads it for every email sent in the sendEmailWithAttachments function.

Comment: @kendi Also there are limits for sending emails with appscript. The limit is 100MB/day bandwidth for uploads. So the app script method doesn't work for any practical email attachment to hundreds of recipients. limits here: https://script.google.com/dashboard